# How to check if an attribute is True in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, boolean, self

I want to look if an `object.est_devoilee is True` : I need to make conditions.

- If object.devoiler is True : do that.
- If object.devoiler is not True: do that.

At first, my objet have self.est_devoilee = False and when I use object.devoiler, it becomes self.est_devoilee = True with that def :

```
def devoiler(self):
    self.est_devoilee = True
```

I have tried

```
if object.devoiler() == True:
```

I have tried

```
 if case.devoiler() is not True:
```

But I feel it's not really checking if self.est_devoilee have been used before. It's as if it always returns true because def devoiler(self): does not return a boolean? I only want to check if object.est_devoilee = True but I don't know how!

Sorry for my spelling, I am french. Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just directly check `if object.est_devoiler:` or `if object.est_devoiler == True:`?

Comment: Because it says that :TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: That would only happen if you did something like `if object.est_devoiler():`, aka putting the parens at the end unnecessarily. You only have to add `()` if you're calling a function.

Comment: Sorry, it's working : I just did not saw there had no parenthesis! Thank you. I'm a begginer at Python, I didn't know this method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `devoiler()` method is not used to get the value of the attribute, it just sets it to `True`. If you want to check it, just access the attribute:

```
if case.est_devoiler:
    # do something
```